# Data Viz with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I got trouble visualizing the following data frame.  My goal is to use `ggplot2::geom_bar()` to visualize the data frame such that, the  number of "usertype" for each day appears on adjacent bars for visual comparisons. Any help please.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Wdays_Trip2 %>% 
group_by(days, usertype) %>% 
summarise(sum(num_trips)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = days)) +
geom_bar()
```

dataframe image has been attached.[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYuW6.png)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to plot your summary statistic `n`, so you should use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar` and provide `n` as your `y` aesthetic. Then, you should map `usertype` to e.g. the fill color and use `position = "dodge"` option in `geom_col()`, like this:

```r
Wdays_Trip2 %>%
  group_by(days, usertype) %>%
  summarise(sum(num_trips)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = days, y = n, fill = usertype) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

As a side note: when posting on SO please kindly provide a minimal reproducible example (data included) as text and not as an image.